# Basic Makefile and header dependencies

Tags: c, header, makefile

I am new to makefiles and I am a bit stuck. I have two c source files called trade.c and report.c . They both depend on a file called acc.h. The acc.h file is composed of two other header files, users.h and resellers.h. I am wondering how you write the dependency of the two header files to the acc.h file. I have so far...

```
OBJECTS = trade.c report.c
CC = gcc

trading: $(OBJECTS)
        $(CC) $(OBJECTS) -o trading

trade.o: trade.c accts.h
        $(CC) -c trade.c

report.o: report.c accts.h
        $(CC) -c report.c
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have no other choice than to add all the header files in the dependency list for the object file, as follows.

```
trade.o: trade.c accts.h users.h resellers.h
        $(CC) -c trade.c
```

Answer (score 0):

In all professional settings I've seen with makefiles, the dependencies were not added manually -- excepted for special cases involving tools like `lex` and `yacc` -- but created automatically, either using options of the compiler (like -MM of gcc), or by using various independent tools like `makedepend` or `mkdep`.

Comment: Sure, but this is not someone setting up a makefile in a professional setting; this is someone learning how to use make. Before you start using automatic tools, know how to do it manually, so you can have a better understanding why and how they work and may fail.