# Makefiles and nested headers

Tags: c++, g++, makefile

My problem is with getting a makefile to run I'm new at this cause normally I just compile from the terminal or use my IDE.

So my problem is probaly with nested header dependencies. I have files that include header files that have header files that have header files. And all those header files have a .cpp file.

So I Googled the Internet to find a thread that said that if you have header files that include header files. You have to add those to the prequisites and that there is no way around this.

[Basic Makefile and header dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5741579)

So I tried this but my case was a little different cause my nested headers also had .cpp files. So I tried adding those to the recipe place that didn't work. So I tried to add the .cpp files that were necessary to the prequisite location. That didn't work either.

```
  1 OBJECTS = main.o MovementHandle.o Cursor.o PromptHandle.o \
  2           Prompt.o NcursesOptions.o RT_Error.o Video.o Frame.o RGB.o
  3 
  4 CXXFLAGS = -std=c++17 -c
  5 LIBS = -lncurses
  6 
  7 drawterm : $(OBJECTS)
  8         g++ -o $(OBJECTS) $(LIBS)
  9 
 10 main.o : main.cpp MovementHandle.o PromptHandle.o
 11         g++ $(CXXFLAGS) main.cpp
 12 
 13 MovementHandle.o : MovementHandle.cpp MovementHandle.h Cursor.o
 14         g++ $(CXXFLAGS) MovementHandle.cpp
 15 
 16 Cursor.o : Cursor.cpp Cursor.h
 17         g++ $(CXXFLAGS) Cursor.cpp
 18 
 19 PromptHandle.o : PromptHandle.cpp PromptHandle.h Prompt.o Video.o
 20         g++ $(CXXFLAGS) PromptHandle.cpp
 21 
 22 Prompt.o : Prompt.cpp Prompt.h Cursor.o NcursesOptions.o
 23         g++ $(CXXFLAGS) Prompt.cpp
 24 
 25 NcursesOptions.o : NcursesOptions.cpp NcursesOptions.h RT_Error.o
 26         g++ $(CXXFLAGS) NcursesOptions.cpp
 27 
 28 RT_Error.o : RT_Error.cpp RT_Error.h
 29         g++ $(CXXFLAGS) RT_Error.cpp
 30 
 31 Video.o : Video.cpp Video.h Frame.o
 32         g++ $(CXXFLAGS) Video.cpp
 33 
 34 Frame.o : Frame.cpp Frame.h RGB.o
 35         g++ $(CXXFLAGS) Frame.cpp
 36 
 37 RGB.o : RGB.cpp RGB.h
 38         g++ $(CXXFLAGS) RGB.cpp
```

So I kept getting this and I know that it means:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/8.3.0/../../../../lib/Scrt1.o: in function `_start':
    (.text+0x24): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [makefile:8: drawterm] Error 1
```

It means that make found a file that I haven't yet properly compiled meaning that make assumes it has a

```
int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

In it but it isn't finding it because it isn't intended to be interpreted like that.

Comment: I just found this what says that i could include the .o files in my prequisites . Im going to tes this out. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15440183/makefile-include-header

Comment: Some possibly helpful reading: [makefile dependency generation](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/2547/makefile-dependency-generation) and [Auto-Dependency Generation](http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/advanced-auto-dependency-generation/)

Comment: i tried reading it but i dont know enough about makefiles to know how to setup including the .d files. So after running: g++ -std=c++17 -MD *.cpp *.h -lncurses. I dont know what to do.

Answer (score 1):

I think that this is inferior line:

```
    g++ -o $(OBJECTS) $(LIBS)
```

When `$(OBJECTS)` is expanded it becomes (probably, because you didn't show declaration of OBJECTS variable):

```
    g++ -o main.o MovementHandle.o Cursor.o ...
```

`-o` option swallows `main.o` as it's argument, so this command means basically:

> build program `main.o` from objects `MovementHandle.o` ...

Most probably you need to change it to something like this:

```
    g++ -o $@ $(OBJECTS)
    # $@ resolves to target, which in your case will be name of executable you want
```

Comment: You got it i was a complete idiot i forget to add the "drawterm" to the "g++  -o $(OBJECTS) $(LIBS)"